# How would you translate "There, but for the grace of God, go I" into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

As in title.  'Illuc sine Dei gratia vadam' doesn't seem quite right.

The phrase derives from 16th century reformer John Bradford's comment as he watched a group of prisoners being led to execution. The essence of the meaning is that it's all up to God what happens — and indeed he himself ended up being burned at the stake.

Comment: The English word “there” is ambiguous, it can mean *illic* or *illuc*. In this expression, I have always interpreted it to mean *illic*. The speaker points to a miscreant being led to the gallows; not to the gallows itself.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the details into your question. You can always edit your own posts to polish them.

Answer (score 1):

The English phrase was popularised by Foxe's Book of Martyrs, sp. John Bradford. The Latin is good, perhaps a little ponderous, except that *'sine'* is probably a typo for *'sinon.'*

*"Huc et illuc,"* Hither and thither, used by Cicero. *Illuc* In that diection.

*Sinon Dei gratia,* If not for the Grace of God.

*Vadam* could be a future indicative "I shall be going;" but is probably present subjunctive, hypothetical, "I may be going."

The conjugation of *vado* is given at [//latin.cactus2000.de](https://latin.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=vadere)
Google *'sinon Dei gratia'* for several other examples of the phrase.

Comment: Indeed, the present subjunctive "I might go" was intended.  I had proposed the preposition 'sine' = without.  But 'sinon' as an adverb would be fine, although I have only come across it as two separate words.

Comment: I would have thought that the verb should be imperfect subjunctive, because the statement is basically a contrafactual condition, isn't it? I it weren't for the grace of God, I would be going there too. Then again, I freely admit that I haven't a clue how contrafactual conditions are done in Ecclesiastical Latin.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *sine* is correct here. I've never heard of *sinon* used in this way, and there is only one unique passage from an obscure Renaissance work that uses the phrase *sinon Dei gratia*. "Sine Dei gratia" (=without the grace of God) is a pretty straightforward translation of the English idiom "but for the grace of God," and it returns tons of results.

Answer (score 0):

Or, as Sir Winston Churchill once said of his rival Sir Stafford Cripps, "There, but for the grace of God, goes God."